Connecting Isolated Paths in Randomly Generated Maps
I am new to game development, I previously created games using tiledmap editor and pygame, but manually creating map was real pain, so i begun to look how can i procedurally generate map, after banging head for few week and googling i finally created a map. However, I'm facing an issue where some paths on the map end up isolated from each other. I'm looking for suggestions or algorithms to connect these isolated parts of the map, ensuring that there is always a continuous path from any point to any other point on the map. The code works on looking at adjacent neighbour but in the end most of the time it cause isolation of part of map by closing path.
from random import random
from pprint import pprint, pformat

WALL = 1
EMPTY = 0
POSSIBLE_WALL_PERCENT = 0.4
ADJACENT_WALL_THRESHOLD = 5
range_X = 1
range_Y = 1

class Map:
    def __init__(self, width: int, height: int):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.grid = [[EMPTY for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]

        self.random_wall_fill()
        self.place_walls()

    def random_wall_fill(self):
        for row in range(self.height):
            for col in range(self.width):
                if random() < POSSIBLE_WALL_PERCENT:
                    self.grid[row][col] = WALL

    def get_adjacent_wall(self, x: int, y: int, range_x: int, range_y: int):
        wall_count: int = 0
        start_x, end_x = x - range_x, x + range_x
        start_y, end_y = y - range_y, y + range_y  

        for i_y in range(start_y, end_y + 1):
            for i_x in range(start_x, end_x + 1):
                if (i_x != x or i_y != y) and self.is_wall(i_x, i_y):
                    wall_count += 1

        return wall_count

    def place_walls(self):
        for y in range(self.height):
            for x in range(self.width):
                if self.grid[y][x] == EMPTY:
                    if self.place_wall_logic(x, y):
                        self.grid[y][x] = WALL

    def place_wall_logic(self, x, y):
        num_walls = self.get_adjacent_wall(x, y, range_X, range_Y)
        if num_walls >= ADJACENT_WALL_THRESHOLD:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def is_wall(self, x: int, y: int):
        if self.out_of_bound(x, y):
            return True
        elif self.grid[y][x] == WALL:
            return True
        return False

    def out_of_bound(self, x: int, y: int):
        if x < 0 or x >= len(self.grid[0]):
            return True
        elif y < 0 or y >= len(self.grid):
            return True
        return False

    def display_map(self):
        for row in self.grid:
            for cell in row:
                if cell == WALL:
                    print("0", end=" ")
                else:
                    print(".", end=" ")
            print() 

    def __repr__(self):
        return pformat(self.grid)

level_map = Map(30, 30)
level_map.display_map()



Algorithm process:

Find any empty area.
Find another empty area closest to this empty area.
Find the shortest path between the two empty areas and fill them with empty areas.
Iterate this process until there is only one empty area on the map.

Code:
def find(self, cell_type):
    for y in range(self.height):
        for x in range(self.width):
            if self.grid[y][x] == cell_type:
                return (y, x)
    return (-1, -1)

def fix_map(self):
    #find any empty cell as start
    start = self.find(EMPTY)
    if start == (-1, -1):
        return
    
    dir_list = [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]
    while True:
        closed_set = {}
        open_list_empty = [start]
        open_list_wall = []

        #find area border
        while open_list_empty:
            current = open_list_empty.pop(0)
            if self.is_wall(current[1], current[0]):
                open_list_wall.append(current)
                continue
            for next_dir in dir_list:
                next_pos = (current[0] + next_dir[0], current[1] + next_dir[1])
                if self.out_of_bound(next_pos[1], next_pos[0]):
                    continue
                if next_pos in closed_set:
                    continue
                closed_set[next_pos] = 1
                open_list_empty.append(next_pos)

        #find another empty area
        predecessor_map = {}
        another_empty_cell = (-1, -1)
        while open_list_wall:
            current = open_list_wall.pop(0)
            if not self.is_wall(current[1], current[0]):
                another_empty_cell = current
                break
            for next_dir in dir_list:
                next_pos = (current[0] + next_dir[0], current[1] + next_dir[1])
                if self.out_of_bound(next_pos[1], next_pos[0]):
                    continue
                if next_pos in closed_set:
                    continue
                closed_set[next_pos] = 1
                predecessor_map[next_pos] = current
                open_list_wall.append(next_pos)

        #cannot find another empty area, break
        if another_empty_cell == (-1, -1):
            break

        #link two empty areas
        while another_empty_cell in predecessor_map:
            predecessor = predecessor_map[another_empty_cell]
            self.grid[predecessor[0]][predecessor[1]] = EMPTY
            another_empty_cell = predecessor

Before:

After:

